# Errors trying to install adldap2-laravel

Tags: laravel-9, adldap

I try to install the package `adldap2/adldap2-laravel` with the command `composer require adldap2/adldap2-laravel` but I get these errors:

```
Info from https://repo.packagist.org: #StandWithUkraine
Using version ^6.1 for adldap2/adldap2-laravel
./composer.json has been updated
Running composer update adldap2/adldap2-laravel
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - adldap2/adldap2-laravel v6.1.6 requires adldap2/adldap2 ^10.1 -> satisfiable by adldap2/adldap2[v10.1.0, ..., v10.4.2].
    - adldap2/adldap2-laravel[v6.1.0, ..., v6.1.1] require illuminate/support ~5.5|~6.0|~7.0 -> found illuminate/support[v5.5.0, ..., 5.8.x-dev, v6.0.0, ..., 6.x-dev, v7.0.0, ..., 7.x-dev] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
    - adldap2/adldap2-laravel[v6.1.2, ..., v6.1.5] require illuminate/support ~5.5|~6.0|~7.0|~8.0 -> found illuminate/support[v5.5.0, ..., 5.8.x-dev, v6.0.0, ..., 6.x-dev, v7.0.0, ..., 7.x-dev, v8.0.0, ..., 8.x-dev] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
    - adldap2/adldap2[v10.1.0, ..., v10.4.0] require psr/log ~1.0 -> found psr/log[1.0.0, ..., 1.1.4] but the package is fixed to 3.0.0 (lock file version) by a partial update and that version does not match. Make sure you list it as an argument for the update command.
    - adldap2/adldap2[v10.4.1, ..., v10.4.2] require psr/simple-cache ~1.0|~2.0 -> found psr/simple-cache[1.0.0, 1.0.1, 2.0.0, 2.x-dev] but the package is fixed to 3.0.0 (lock file version) by a partial update and that version does not match. Make sure you list it as an argument for the update command.
    - Root composer.json requires adldap2/adldap2-laravel ^6.1 -> satisfiable by adldap2/adldap2-laravel[v6.1.0, ..., v6.1.6].

Use the option --with-all-dependencies (-W) to allow upgrades, downgrades and removals for packages currently locked to specific versions.
You can also try re-running composer require with an explicit version constraint, e.g. "composer require adldap2/adldap2-laravel:*" to figure out if any version is installable, or "composer require adldap2/adldap2-laravel:^2.1" if you know which you need.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.
```

The laravel version is `v9.3.8`. I am not sure if I break something when I run `composer require adldap2/adldap2-laravel --with-all-dependencies`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is due to adldap2/adldap2 package requiring the psr/simple-cache 2.0.0 but the Laravel framework is using 3.0.0

Downgrading, the psr/simple-cache to 2.0.0 will not make an issue.

Answer (score 0):

I executed `composer require adldap2/adldap2-laravel --with-all-dependencies` to enable composer to install, upgrade or downgrade the required required dependencies.